# Google in-app re-buy managed item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

Is it possible that I can re-buy a manged item?
I am testing my android app and I did not use the checkPayload method when I bought the item first.

now I implemented the checkPayload method and of course now it tells me that the payload isn't the same... Is it possible I can reject the first time buy and re-buy it again?

I anyway would like to re-buy it again, so I can test my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancel transaction from google play console, wait a lot of time (few hours) and you will be able to purchase it again.
BTW - you should check inventory on Google Play to get purchased items in case of some issues during purchase (i.e. crash between purchase and notifying the application).

Comment: Thank you I just figured this out as well... but instead of waiting for a long time I just killed the google play threads... this way it will check automatically online for any changes...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the latest version of the Google In-App Billing system, in which case you can 'consume' a managed product (all products are managed in v3). Once consumed, the user can purchase the item again. Since this is for testing, you'll want to disable this consumption in your release build.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Consume